# SSRS Export to xls without Details

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

My Report shows the data like in the upper part of the picture:

[image]

I can Use the toggel buttons to show details (yellow).

Like in the lower part of the picture I want to prevent this by using a parameter. (Not just hide, but **prevent from xls export**)

My goul would be to have a parameter, that prevents the details from beeing exported to xls.
(Not even as closed toggeled details.)
*Print Details = No*

Or allow details to be exported.
*Print Details = Yes*

Is it possible to set this up with parameters? Or do I need to create a separate report for that?
I tried the visability options but even when hidden, the details are exported.

Comment: there is rowvisibility/columnvisibility and visibility of cell, you ncould try toggle the cell visibility via parameter without ability to toggle with reportitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the Group's hidden property to

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML"
```

This simply prevents the group from being rendered if your are exporting to Excel.

*Note: if using the old Excel format the rederformat name value is just "EXCEL"*

However, this will not work if you have "toggle on report item also set". In this case you would need to set the visibility based on your parameter.